# Batch conversion of jpg to pdf

Tags: pdf, command-line, jpeg

I have huge amount of jpeg files each being a photho of a page of from a historical document. Now I want to (batch) create pdf files out of these, preferably making those files representing one document into separate pdf files, with the pages in the correct order. Filenames are constructed like this "date y p id optional.jpg" where y is the running number if several documents have the same date, p is the page number, id is the number of the photo from the camera and finally optional sometimes is present and contains optional info on the document. All pieces are separated by a space.
I was hoping to find a possibility to use the built in Microsoft PDF writer, but have not found a comand line interface for that. I can of course make a script from the directory listing, only that I know the command line interface of the application to make the script for. A bonus would be if each page of the created pdf file could contain parts of the filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't against a python script there is an image to pdf library known as img2pdf. The PyPi link can be found [here](https://pypi.org/project/img2pdf/) and I would be happy to do up a quick script for you

EDIT:
A tutorial can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-image-to-pdf-using-i)

EDIT 2:
This should do

```
## Import libraries ##
import img2pdf, os
from Pillow import Image
# sets an empty list var to store the dir
dirofjpgs = "PUT DIRECTORY HERE" # formatting is C:\\User not C:\User\
pathforpdfs = "PUT DIRECTORY HERE"
# change dir to working dir
os.chdir(dirofjpgs)
NameOfFiles = []
# sets and empty list to store the names of files
ExtOfFiles = []
# sets and empty list to store the names and extentions of files
self_file = os.path.basename(__file__)
for i in range(1, len(os.listdir(os.curdir))): # for every item in the current dir
    if (os.path.splitext((os.listdir(os.curdir))[i])[1]) != ".ini": # if the item ends doesnt end in .ini which is a windows file
        NameOfFiles.append(os.path.splitext((os.listdir(os.curdir))[i])[0])  # adds the Name of the file into the NameOfFiles list
        ExtOfFiles.append(os.path.splitext((os.listdir(os.curdir))[i])[1]) # adds the Name and Extention of the file into the ExtOfFiles list

# for every item in the nameoffiles list
for i in range(len(NameOfFiles)):
    # open image with pillow
    image = Image.open(NameOfFiles[i], ExtOfFiles[i])
    # convert with img2pdf
    pdf_values = img2pdf.convert(image.filename)
    # save as pdf in dir
    file = open(pathforpdfs, "wb")
    file.write(pdf_values)
    #close
    image.close()
    file.close()
    print(str(i+1), "/", len(NameOfFiles))
```

mg2pdf-module/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip! I am certainly not against python, but not (yet) a user of it. Therefore I would of course very much appreciate a starter script for my project...